# Usage of the verb “gehören” — is “zu” required or not?

Tags: preposition, verb-usage

I have a grammar book that explained usage of the verb gehören, like:

> Es gehört meiner Frau.

It did not include using someone’s name like:

> The dog belongs to David.

I looked it up on Google Translate and it suggested:

> Der Hund gehört zu David.

But it also suggested:

> Es gehört zu meiner Frau.

So is it correct to say the following?

> Der Hund gehört David.

I know Google Translate sometimes gets it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sorry, my keyboard has no umlaut

In that case append an *e* to the vowel you want to make an Umlaut of: ä->ae, ö->oe, ü->ue, Ä->Ae etc. That's how Germans do it. (note this doesn't always apply in the opposite direction.)

Google translate at best can make a good guess as it doesn't know the meaning of a sentence.

> Der Hund gehört zu David.

implies that the dog and David cannot be thought separated. The verb is *gehören zu*, as in *zueinander gehören* (belong to each other).

> Der Hund gehört David.

in contrary only says David is the owner of the dog. The verb is *gehören* with a different meaning.

So

> Es gehört meiner Frau.

can be used for anything your wife is the owner of. While

> Es gehört **zu** meiner Frau.

can be used only for things you can't think of being separated from your wife. For example, her temper.

Comment: Das David und der Hund nicht voneinander getrennt gedacht werden können finde ich mehrere Stufen zu stark ausgedrückt. Mir gelingt das problemlos. Der Hund könnte sterben, David könnte sterben, ein äußerer Zwang könnte sie trennen - dennoch würde man sagen können, dass sie zusammen gehören.

Comment: Genau das bedeutet, dass sie nicht getrennt voneinander gedacht werden können. Sie gehören zusammen, selbst wenn einer davon unter der Erde ist.

Comment: Nein, dann gehörten sie zusammen, Vergangenheitsform. 2 Kinder können auch eine gemeinsame Katze haben und von jedem könnte man sagen, dass es mit der Katze zusammengehört. Die Eltern könnten sich aber trennen und jeder kann ein Kind zu sich nehmen aber nur einer die Katze. Das kann man sich doch denken.

Comment: Ich denke, du verkomplizierst die Sache unnötig.

Comment: Plus one for "her temper" :-)

Answer (score 1):

The standard translation of *to belong to someone* is *jemandem gehören* — no preposition.

> Diese Villa gehört mir, diese Jacht gehört mir, dieser Privatjet gehört mir auch. Der Maserati gehört aber meiner Frau.

Typically, this is used to indicate *possession.* And possession is typically associated with *objects,* hence *jemandem gehören* is usually not used with people — and if you use it for people it may sound offensive.

> Das sind unsere Sklaven. Peter gehört mir, Paul gehört meiner Frau.

---

*Zu jemandem gehören* is a different phrase. It does not mean *to belong to somebody* in a possessional sense but rather *to belong (close) to somebody* in a locational sense.

> [Er gehört zu mir, wie mein Name an der Tür.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoSplOPXZQs)

The singer doesn’t want to *possess* him, as she might want to possess jewellery or money. She wants the person to be close to her and feel at home there.

Similarly for the name: she doesn’t want to claim possession like one would for a brand name. Instead, she wants the name to be seen as connected to her.

The phrase can be interpreted as very similar to:

> Er gehört *hierher*

This example further exemplifies the locational aspect of the expression.

Comment: Just for reference: _„Er gehört zu mir…“_ is the title of one of [Marianne Rosenberg's great songs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoSplOPXZQs).

Comment: Haha, das war auch das erste Beispiel, da mir eingefallen ist.